# $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|^{\frac{1}{2}} |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\xi|^{\frac{1}{2}} |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d\xi = \infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

Is there a $f$  such that

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|^{\frac{1}{2}} |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\xi|^{\frac{1}{2}} |\hat{f}(\xi)|^2 d\xi = \infty$, where $\hat{}$ denote the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$$
f(x)=|x|^{-1/8}\,K_{1/8}(x),
$$
where $K_a$ is the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1), then
$$
\hat f(\xi)=C\,(1+\xi^2)^{-3/8}
$$
for some constant $C$. $K_a$ has exponential decay at $\infty$ and $|\xi|^{1/2}|\hat f(\xi)|^2\sim|\xi|^{-1}$ as $\xi\to\infty$.

Comment: Why $\hat{f} (\xi) = C (1+{\xi}^2)^{\frac{-3}{8}}$?

Comment: I computed it with Mathematica. Well, in fact I computed the inverse Fourier transform of $(1+\xi^2)^{-3/8}$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.